# Assign attribute values

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, product-attribute

I trying make event observer with save_after. 
This is an attempt to set Meta Title automatically when saving my products.
**Creating a module**:
So looks like the folder structure:
[image]

**Observer.php code:**

```
<?php    
class Unnamed_MyModule_Model_Observer
    {
        public function catalog_product_save_after($observer)
        {
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            if(!$product->getMetaTitle()){
                $name = $product->getName();           
                $metaTitle = str_replace(' - ', ' ', $name);
                $product->setMetaTitle($metaTitle);
                $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'meta_title');
            }
        }
    }
```

**config.xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<global>
    <events>          
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers> 
                <unnamed_mymodule>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Unnamed/MyModule</class>
                    <method>catalog_product_save_after</method>
                </unnamed_mymodule>
            </observers> 
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events> 
</global>
</code>
```

**magento/app/etc/modules Unnamed_MyModule.xml code:**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Unnamed_MyModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Unnamed_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

It seems to me that there are no errors. But It is not work.
optional: magento 1.9, CE, I'm a beginner.
Tell me what is wrong?
 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There issue with your config.xml, you did not define the model alias.

It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Unnamed_MyModule>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Unnamed_MyModule>
  </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mymoduleunnamed>
                <class>Unnamed_MyModule_Model</class>
            </mymoduleunnamed>
        </models>
  </global>
    <global>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <mymoduleunnamed>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>mymoduleunnamed/observer</class>
                        <method>catalog_product_save_after</method>
                    </mymoduleunnamed>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>       
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

So you have two options.

1. Define your model name under the `<global>` node,
2. Set the full path to the observer on the event,

**Define model**

```
<models>
    <your_module>
        <class>Your_Module_Model</class>
    </your_module>
</models>
```

Then update the class on the event to match:

```
<class>your_module/observer</class>
```

**Set the full path**

Simply update the class part of your event to match the full class name of your observer:

```
<class>Your_Module_Model_Observer</class>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, from your configuration i see that you haven't entered correct observer name in configuration, so you should enter a full observer's class name or short:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <global>
     <events>          
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers> 
                <unnamed_mymodule>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <!--  using full name -->
                    <class>Unnamed_MyModule_Model_Observer</class> 
                    <method>catalog_product_save_after</method>
                </unnamed_mymodule>
            </observers> 
        </catalog_product_save_after>
      </events> 
    </global>           
</config>
```

Try it. Clean cache before!

Answer (score 1):

It thought,it will good idea `to call catalog_product_save_before event instead of catalog_product_save_after.`

Modified config.xml value is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Unnamed_MyModule>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Unnamed_MyModule>
  </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mymoduleunnamed>
                <class>Unnamed_MyModule_Model</class>
            </mymoduleunnamed>
        </models>
  </global>
    <global>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <mymoduleunnamed>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>mymoduleunnamed/observer</class>
                        <method>catalog_product_save_after</method>
                    </mymoduleunnamed>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>
        </events>
    </global>       
</config>
```

Observer.php code is:

```
<?php    
class Unnamed_MyModule_Model_Observer
    {
        public function catalog_product_save_after($observer)
        {
            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();;
            if(is_null($product->getData('meta_title')){
                $name = $product->getData('name());           
                $metaTitle = str_replace(' - ', ' ', $name);

                //$product->setMetaTitle($metaTitle);
                //$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'meta_title');
        $product->setData('meta_title',$finalTemWeight);
            }
        }
    }
```